I am running php artisan serve but error During inheritance of ArrayAccess
I am running on my laravel project
php artisan serve

but show error

During inheritance of ArrayAccess Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection

Please help me
How to i can resolved this problem

Check your php version in cli and php/laravel version in composer.json, probably there is a conflict between the two versions.

On my linux php installed version is 8.1.2
And on composer.json is "php": "^7.3|^8.1"

This question is similar to: inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Collection::offsetExists($key). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your project is not a new one, I suggest that you downgrade PHP. If it's a new project (or small enough) upgrade your laravel to 8 https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade then to 9 https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade

This error usually occurs due to a PHP version mismatch. If you’re seeing this error, it’s likely because your PHP version is lower than the version required by Laravel.

My laravel version 7.29 and requirement PHP >= 7.2.5
On my laptop php version installed is 8.1.2

Update composer.json to require "laravel/framework": "^8.0" or "laravel/framework": "^9.0"

Run composer update to install the updated dependencies

Change  the function return type
public funciton phpDemo():void{
}

